# lamp-server wants to install mysql but i want it to use already installed MariaDB

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, mysql, lamp, tasksel

i want to install lamp-server in ubuntu 10.10 (the end goal is to install redmine), i am using

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

However after downloading packages it asks for a root password for mysql, now, in my machine i have already an instance of MariaDB 5.24 and i want it to use that (not download or install real mysql), what do i need to do in order to properly configure it with the right database?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [bgvaughan](https://askubuntu.com/users/14663/bgvaughan) stated, **tasksel** provides package 'groups' in order to setup complete and correctly configured, fully integrated services.

'M' from the 'LAMP' initials refers to mySQL, therefore tasksel will automatically try to install and configure mysql-server.

If you want to use mariaDB, you should install **apache** & **php** separately:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`
`sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

I haven't worked with mariaDB, but i've heard that it's a binary drop-in replacement for mysql, so i guess it should be working ok.

Answer (score 2):

tasksel is just a means to install a meta-package, which is a list of packages. There's no particular configuration involved beyond installing the packages themselves. You could skip tasksel and just install the packages you intend to use, or you could use tasksel and then purge mysql, or you could just keep mysql, which shouldn't interfere with your existing database installation.